# Cytoscape.js: change layout dynamically

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to change Cytoscape.js layout dynamically based on radio buttons.

I have:

```
<input type="radio" name="layout" value="preset" checked>
<input type="radio" name="layout" value="breadthfirst">
```

and

```
$("input:radio[name=layout]").click(function() {
    var layout = $(this).val();
    cy.layout({ name: layout });        
});
```

The values from the buttons pass correctly, i checked them with alerts.

What am i missing?

Comment: `cy.layout({name : SOMELAYOUTTYPE})` works just fine for me: http://jsbin.com/senifu/edit?js,output - maybe there is something else causing a problem your code?

Comment: yes, something else caused the problem, it works now, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the document:http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.layout,you will need to use `cy.layout( options )`

First, you need to call `cy.layout(options)` to set layout, then simply call `layout.run()` to make it works.

The code will be like below:

```
// cy here is an instance of Cytoscape
var layout = cy.layout({
      name: 'random'
    });

    layout.run();
```

You can find more layouts here: http://js.cytoscape.org/#demos